# My dictionary sometimes lists two imperfective forms

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, вид

Consider the verb to send, which my dictionary translates as *посылать (imp.), слать (imp.), послать (perf.). My question is about those cases in which there are *two* imperfective forms, like in this one. Is there a general rule about the difference, if there are two?

Comment: This is called "secondary imperfective". See Terrence Wade's "Comprehensive Russian Grammar" (§ 248).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite a common case:

- слать - посла́ть - посыла́ть
- есть - съесть - съеда́ть
- жечь - сжечь - сжига́ть, etc

The prefixed imperfective verb normally denotes a periodic action while the unprefixed verb describes a continuous action:

- Он ка́ждую неде́лю посыла́ет ей пода́рок. - He sends her a gift every week.
- Он постоя́нно шлёт ей пода́рки. - He sends her gifts all the time.
- Он всё вре́мя ест. - He eats all the time / He can't stop eating.
- Он съеда́ет таре́лку ка́ши ка́ждый день. - He eats one plate of porridge every day.

Comment: See also this answer: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/14373/2104