# Choosing between multiple perfective forms

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, вид

I recently found in my dictionary the triple: *проща́ться (нв.)*, *прости́ться (св.)*, *попроща́ться (св.)*, for *to say goodbye*.

What do the two imperfective forms mean here in particular?

Is there a general scheme for the meaning in such cases where there are two perfective forms not only differing by a prefix?

Comment: I remember your similar question about imperfective ) https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/my-dictionary-sometimes-lists-two-imperfective-forms - yep, it's. a non-trivial topic in Russian )

Comment: @shabunc Yes, the only difference is that here I have two perfective forms.

Comment: sure, it's a different question, nobody argues with that )

Answer (score 1):

*Проститься* often means to say goodbye forever or for a long time.
Sometimes it refers to the custom of asking forgiveness before taking one's leave.

> *Они простились с усопшим.*
>
> *Мы простились и он уехал* (far away and for a long time).

*Прощаться* (*попрощаться*) means to say goodbye before parting for a short period of time.
Sometimes it may be applied in the case of parting for a long time or forever.

> *мы попрощались*. (and we will see each other tomorrow or soon)

Comment: I upvoted your answer but, as I read it, I was thinking that this may vary across regions. I mean, *попрощаться с усопшим* sounds ideomatic to me too...

Answer (score 0):

"Прости́ться" in the meaning of "saying goodbye" is considered archaic in modern Russian where "попроща́ться" would be used instead.
For example:

```
Царь с царицею простился,
В путь-дорогу снарядился,
И царица у окна
Села ждать его одна.
```

In the modern language, the first line would be expressed as "царь с царицей попрощался".
"Прости́ться" can still be used when saying goodbye forever — like leaving for good or a final farewell to the deceased.

Comment: «"Прости́ться" in the meaning of "saying goodbye" is considered archaic in modern Russian language» ???  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8L9AmmtgG8

Comment: Yup, I don't feel myself archaic (yet) but I perceive *проститься* as a "normal" word...